# Creating a javascript variable from an JSON file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

i have php var same this in index.php file :

```
<?php
        $aoData = '
        { "name": "count", "value": "5" } ,
        { "name": "tbl", "value": "member" } ,
        { "name": "0", "value": "id" } ,
        { "name": "1", "value": "fname" } ,
        { "name": "2", "value": "lname" } ,
        { "name": "3", "value": "username" } ,
        { "name": "4", "value": "mail" }
        ';
        include("main.php");
?>
```

i need send this php var as js function parameters in main.php and i use json like this:

```
<input type="button" onClick="run(<?php echo htmlentities(json_encode($aoData)); ?>)"
```

and i need use this var in load.js as a parameters. my load.js is like this :

```
function run(data1){
    var oTable =$('#example').dataTable( {
            aoData.push(**data1**)},
        "onblur" : "disable",
        "select" : true })}
```

but this way doesn't work.

Comment: I tried it. Does not run

Comment: Why do you encode already encoded array?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your data is already `json_encode()`ed in your main PHP file. You should just be able to echo is using `htmlentities()` to make sure it is attribute-safe.

So `run( <?php echo htmlentities( $aoData ); ?> )`

---

Just as a note, what you're doing with `json_encode()` would work if `$aoData` looked like:

```
$aoData = array(
    array( 'name' => '', 'value' => '' ),
    array( 'name' => '', 'value' => '' ),
    array( 'name' => '', 'value' => '' ),
);
```

`json_encode()` takes an array/object and turns it into JSON, which is a string that is formatted similarly to how your `$aoData` is currently.

Comment: @Oveys Can you give us more details about why it is not running? Otherwise we won't be able to help you. For instance, error messages that appear when you try to run.

Comment: i tried your second offer , but doesn't run. when i run program, in Mozilla console i have many script error from line 1 jquery.min.js file. i think this is a problem from htmlentities() function

Comment: i solved all of problem. but i have a little problem. i have 2 params , $aoData and $aoCol . $aoCol is an object , but $aoData is array. and it is a json object , how can i send this obj as array to js function ?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be hand-coding json in PHP. There are too many potential encoding issues that can develop from this. Make a PHP array and then encode that.

```
$aoData = array();
$aoData[] = array('name' => 'count', 'value => 5);
...

echo json_encode($aoData);
```

Answer (score 0):

The data table function needs two parameters. But you are pass one variable to that function.
Look through the documentation of datatable and their input types.

You can use php variable directly on your javascript function its on a same page.

Try to alert the javascript params for check yourself 
Your json.encode not handled correctly. Already you have a json string. Then why you need encode

Answer (score 0):

I actually agree with Tyler Carter
you should encode your JSON from a PHP array.
The following example is completely independent and you can see the result in your console

```
<?php
$aoData = json_encode(array(
  array("name"  => "count", "value" => "5"),
    array("tbl" => "count", "value" => "member"),
    array("0"   => "count", "value" => "id"),
    array("1"   => "count", "value" => "fname"),
    array("2"   => "count", "value" => "lname"),
    array("3"   => "count", "value" => "username"),
    array("4"   => "count", "value" => "mail"),
));
?>
<html>
<body>
<input type="button" onclick="console.log(<?=htmlentities($aoData);?>)"  value="run"/>;
</body>
</html>
```